# How can i Implement a video player that handle video streaming in Android App

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

In my Android Application I want to reproduce the streaming videos. 
For now I currently use the video view but It might works better.. I have this problems :

- some files it doesnt execute -> error (1 ,-1005)
- video streaming buffering starts after long times

What do you suggest to use instead of videoview ?

I see more Applications that play streaming video inside the app without this problems, but I don't understand what they using for that result. Maybe webview with javascript player ???

Comment: you can use ExoPlayer or the good old MediaPlayer. Both will support what you want, but exoplayer provides more flexibility and options as compared to mediaplayer, but is a little bit more complicated and requires some more setup

Comment: I've seen that Dash is a good format for video streaming, where are you storing your videos and how to you convert them to dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your min sdk is 16 and above use [Exo player](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

You will find detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo).

Answer (score 3):

you can try surfaceView :

```
 SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
 surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
           mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
           mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
           mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think surfaceview is Better then videoview?